# BST insert not working

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I was trying to implement a code for binary search trees. Problem is following code is not working but it works if I pass double pointer to insert funcion like insert(struct bst** node, data). I think it should also work with passing single pointers. Can anyone explain what is the error here ?

```
void insert(struct bst* node, int data )
{
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        printf("here with %d\n",data);
        node = (struct bst*)malloc(sizeof(struct bst));
        node->data = data;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;
    }
    if(data < node->data)
    {
        insert(node->left,data);
    }
    else if(data > node->data)
    {
        insert(node->right,data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the value of the pointer passed to a function, you should pass it as pointer to a pointer.

```
void alloc_int(int** p)
{
  *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
}

int main()
{
  int* p = NULL;
  alloc_int(&p);
  *p = 10; // here memory for p is allocated so you can use it
  free(p);
  return 0;
}
```

The same thing in your example. You have to pass an address of pointer to change its value (value of the pointer is address of actual data).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change a pointer's value, you should pass the address of the pointer (as `struct node **`).

With your code:

```
node = (struct bst*)malloc(sizeof(struct bst));
```

the value of `node` changes in the `insert` function, but doesn't change the variable in the calling function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to modify the pointers in what will become the parents of `node`.  When you make the recursive call `insert(node->left,data)`, if `node` (the parent of the new node) has no left child (`left==null`), you are calling `insert(null,data)`.  The first `if` statement will then create the new node and assign its data, but there will be no way to hook that node into the tree.  Also, since `insert` doesn't return the new node,
the node is lost forever.

A quick hack to fix this would be to return the new node:

```
struct bst *insert(struct bst* node, int data, struct bst* parent )
{ /// Note new return value
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        printf("here with %d\n",data);
        node = (struct bst*)malloc(sizeof(struct bst));
        node->data = data;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;
        return node; /// NEW - send it back to the parent
    }

    if(data < node->data)
    {
        node->left = insert(node->left,data); /// save the new child if there wasn't one
        return node; /// otherwise, send back the node so the tree doesn't change.
    }
    else //if(data > node->data) /// On equal keys, add to the right
    {
        node->right = insert(node->right,data);
        return node;
    }
}
```

(disclaimer: code not yet tested)